# Specifying assumptions at the start of a piece of code

Tags: assumptions

I am aware of the use of 'Assumptions' or 'Assuming' to attach to certain operations (e.g. integrals) to aid Mathematica. Is there a way of listing asssumptions at the beginning of a piece of code such that every evaluation thereafter makes use of them, rather than writing the assumptions in every evaluation? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 6):

You can check if using

```
Block[{$Assumptions =...}, ...]
```

will do the trick for you.

`$Assumptions` is a global variable, so the `Block` construct just plays the the role of localising the effect of changing it -- thanks @Natas in comments.

Sorry, I'm a newbie here so don't know how to refer to the comment

Comment: Perhaps you should also point out that `$Assumptions` can be set outside of block? I think OP is referring to the options `Assumptions` (see parenthetical remark in OP).

Comment: @Chris - Note that "such that every evaluation thereafter makes use of them" will in general not be achieved since assumptions only affect functions that make use of the `Assumptions` option. Consequently almost "every evaluation" would need to include `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` to ensure that the assumptions were used. This could significantly impact performance. Further, you would still need to explicitly include the assumptions in the system of equalities and inequalities given to `Solve`, `Reduce`, `FindInstance`, or other functions that take constraints.